# Need help regarding proper string encryption decryption

Tags: java, android, string, encryption, byte

I need help regarding the string encryption and decryption in java i have string having length 16 i need to encode it and also decode it but i need encoded string to be alphanumeric and symbols only that user can type from mobile and of the size same as plain text i tried Md5 and DES but MD5 is one way only and DES encoded string is not only alphanumeric and proper symbols tried some other ways not finding proper solution.

Comment: http://trumpetpower.com/Papers/Crypto/Playfair

Comment: @nik: Playfair is not reversible as it adds extra characters to break up pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert every character of the encoded string to its hex representation. In this case the resulting string will be alphanumeric.

Comment: ya but length of the string will be increased ? as already encode string size will be large and converting hex will increase length

Comment: I think you can't convert any string to alphanumeric string without increasing its length.

Comment: ya but is their way that i can use any algorithm first to encode so byte or length can be compressed and convert to BASE64 or HEX ?

Comment: It depends on the content of the string. You can't be sure any string can be encoded and not extended. If you give more information about strings you want to encode, maybe I'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Vigenère cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenere_cipher) can be restricted to any desired character set and has the cyphertext the same length as the plaintext.  It is not as secure as a modern cypher, but has uses in low security applications.  A determined attacker will be able to break Vigenère.

Comment: hum ya i know tht algo. its more possible to breakable

Comment: @ud_an: Vigenère can be made unbreakable if you can generate a true random key (**not** pseudo-random) that is at least as long as the plaintext.  And you only use that key once.  Under those conditions Vigenère becomes a One Time Pad.  Any minor deviation and it is breakable again.